# PHP: Extending Classes

Tags: php, class, extends

I'm absolutely sure this has been asked before, but I cannot find it anywhere.

So I have two classes. A and B

```
class classA 
{ 
    public $var1;
    public $classbVar;
    public function init()
    {
        // This is here because other script is run before it is called
        // in the live code.
        // it basically checks that the file exists. There is a reason for this.
        if (file_exists('classB.php')) 
        {
            require_once('classB.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "An error has occurred loading the second class.";
        }
        $this->var1 = "something";
        $this->classbVar = new classB
        echo $this->classbVar->doSomething();

    }
}
```

In a separate file

```
class classB extends classA
{
     public function doSomething()
     {
          echo $this->var1;
     }
 }
```

In a third file, I'm calling classA and running the init function. This is not real code, but identical to what I have written.

So why doesn't this work. if I VAR_DUMP I get null.... What have I done wrong or misunderstood?

LET ME BE MORE CLEAR:

There is a third file which calls classA as below;

```
require_once('classA.php')
$classA = new classA;
$classA->init();
```

My apologies for any confusion, I did this on the fly a little bit, as I am sure I am missing something simple here. Surely the way I am trying to do this will work somehow.

Comment: What does the exact code look like that is failing?

Comment: Basically this....`require_once (classA.php);
    $classA = new classA();
    
    $classA->init();`

Comment: The exact code is over 500 lines long, it's stumbling with the extends not working properly, or at least not as I had expected. It's also across 6 files, from start to where it's stumbling. Everything up to that point is working fine, but this is the first time I've played with extending classes, I grew up on procedural, and can do that rather well, but classes are apparently much better and easier to modify in the future

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here that cause your output to be null:

1. You are generating a new `$classA` object and any values you set on that, will not automatically be set on the `$classbVar` object as that is a completely different object of a class that just extends the `A` class, not the `$classA` object you have just generated. 
   With the exception of a static property of course...
2. If you want to set the value of a property in an object, you need `$this->var1` instead of `$var1`. 
   **Note** if you set the value in your `$classA` object, it is still not set for the `$classbVar` object.

Comment: So this is the complete opposite to how I've understood it then. The whole inherited isn't once the second class is called, it's from the second class to the first.

Comment: @ukitconsultant An object of a certain class inherits the characteristics of the *class* that it extends but it inherits nothing from another *object*. Generating an object in a class that extends that same class does make things a bit confusing :-)

Comment: So how do you pass values between classes then? Have I missed something completely stupid here.

Comment: @ukitconsultant You don't pass values between classes: An object of the extended class simply inherits the properties and methods of its parent so you can use them as if they are part of that same class.

Comment: So how do you pass data from one class to the other without breaking out of the class entirely?

Comment: For example; I have three classes, classA, classB, and classC. The full directory path is stored in classA, but only set in classB, classA is the parent class for both classB and classC. How would I access that data in classC?

Comment: @ukitconsultant You are mixing up objects and classes; an object of a class that extends another class simply has all properties and methods of the parent class. But you still have to set them, they are not shared between objects (except for static properties).

Answer (score 0):

1. Put require_once above class declaration (this is not big issue but it's more clear)
2. Assign variables to class properties because they way you did the scope of them is only within the method.

   `$var1 = "something";`

should be changed to

```
    $this->var1 = "something";
```

Also the class values are not shared unless they are declared as static. So to access the properties from parent class you can do following:

```
class classA 
{ 
    public $var1;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->var1 = "something";
    }
}

// other file
require_once("A class location");

class classB extends classA
{
     public function doSomething()
     {
          echo $this->var1;
     }
}

$b = new classB();
$b->init();
$b->doSomething();
```

or more clean way:

```
class A 
{ 
    protected $var1;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->var1 = "something";
    }
}

// other file
require_once("A class location");

class B extends A
{
     public function doSomething()
     {
          return $this->var1;
     }
}

$b = new B();
echo $b->doSomething();

// or shorter syntax

echo {new B()}->doSomething();
```

Instead of using `require_once()` it's better to use [PSR-4 autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/).